# automatically upload a scanned web QRCODE in my WebView?

Tags: android, webview, camera, android-camera, qr-code

I want WebView automatically load a scanned QR code 
my code looks like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.i("Barcode Result", contents);
                WebView.loadUrl("SCAN_RESULT");
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("Barcode Result","Result canceled");
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: what do you expect `mWebView.loadUrl("SCAN_RESULT");
` to do?

Comment: to load the scanned result in WebView but thets not work

Comment: can somebody help me please

Comment: Of course that does not work. Why would it? It's no url that you present but an English word. WebView does not understand English. Why aren't you telling who did the scanning? What does String content contain?

Comment: I have the QR scanner from ZXing

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: i tray  this but
 public void loadScript(String script){      
      mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + script + "})()");             }}

Comment: Thanks a lot but I've found the answer 
WebView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

Answer (score 0):

When someone have a problem with loading the QR CODE automatically in webview
put se it down work great

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("Barcode Result", contents);
            WebView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("Barcode Result","Result canceled");
        }
    }
}
```